# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object while converting result to array

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch multiple rows in form of an array and then converting it to json

Heres my code :

```
public function getTest($standard,$chapid,$count)
{


   if($count>0)
{


    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT question from questions where standard=? and chapterId=? ORDER BY rand()");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $standard,$chapid);
    $result=$stmt->execute();
    echo $result;
    $stmt->close();
    $rows = $this->resultToArray($result);
    echo json_encode($rows);// Array of rows



 }

else
{

    $rows["success"] = 0;
    $rows["message"] = "Posts NOT Available!";
}



echo json_encode($rows);


}

public function resultToArray($result) {
    $rows["success"] = 1;
    $rows["message"] = "Post Available!";
    $rows["posts"]   = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) // <--Getting ERROR OVER HERE
{
    array_push($rows["posts"], $row);
}
return $rows;
}
```

I am new to php so I can't figure out why I am getting an error in `resultToArray()` function on while line.

Comment: Because $result isn't a valid object?  fetch_assoc() is a method, I think, usually, of a MySQLi object.  $result isn't a MySQLi object.  It appears you're actually using PDO ... what happens if you "var_dump($result)" up there?  Does it give any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the results of your query; `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` will return each result as an associative array:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
 array_push($results, $row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$result` passed to your function `resultToArray()` is in fact a [bool](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php). You are passing the wrong variable.

Comment: oh got it...so what can i do to convert it into an array?

Comment: I want to get actual result not the bool variable?

Comment: The get_result() function is giving me an undefined function error